# Can electron's --log-file flag capture main console logs, or only renderer logs?

Tags: logging, electron, electron-packager

I've been trying to figure out a way to log my electron app's main console logs in production, *without* having to install an additional npm package such as `electron-logger`.  When starting electron manually from the command line, this is no problem of course; I can just pipe the output to a logfile. Similarly, if starting via `npm start`, I can just create a `package.json` like this:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1",
  "description": "an app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron . | tee myfile.txt"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "latest"
  },
}
```

However, if the app is packaged into an executable, by say `electron-packager` or `electron-builder`, that `start` command is ignored, and the file is not generated.

I discovered that electron has some [built-in command line options](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/command-line-switches) for logging: notably, `log-file=FILE` and `--enable-logging`. I can even set these directly in my `main.js` as follows:

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('log-file', 'myfile.txt');
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('enable-logging');
```

This works even when the app is bundled as an exe, but it only appears to capture console output from the renderer process (what would display in the browser's debugging tools.)

**Is there a way to get electron's built in logs to capture main console statements as well? Or is limited to renderer logs?** The documentation was unclear to me on this. I did find [this link,](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/application-debugging) which gave me the impression that `--log-file` only capture's the chromium logs (which I assume are only the renderer logs?) But I was unsure if my assumption was correct.